# I have to click twice to add / remove item because of IE Cache with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, internet-explorer, caching

I have an application built with Node.js and AngularJS. And I am making simple CRUD operations.
In chrome, everything works fine, but in Internet Explorer, because of cache, I have to refresh data manually.

After a few hours I found a solution but it still doesn't work 100%.
For example:

1. Enter the name in the textbox (*"Partner_name_1"*) and press `Add`
2. Nothing happens
3. Again enter the name in the textbox (*"Partner_name_2"*) and press `Add` (or just simply refresh the page)
4. On the list below appears (*"Partner_name_1"*)
5. ...and you can repeat from the beginning

Here is my code

View:

```
form(name="AddPartner")
            |Name: 
            input(type='text', name='name' ng-model="dataPartner.name")

            button(type='add', ng-click="addPartner(dataPartner)")
            |   Add


table(style="width:100%")
    tr(ng-repeat="partner in partnerList")
        td
            p {{ partner.name }}
        td
            button(type='remove', ng-click="removePartner(partner._id)")
                | Remove
```

Angular script:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
    }]);

    myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout){


    $scope.loadPartnersData = function () {
    $http.get("/main/partner-list").then(function(result) {
    $scope.partnerList = result.data.partnerList;
    });
    };
    $scope.loadPartnersData();

    var addPartner = '/main/addPartner'
    var removePartner = '/main/removePartner'

    $scope.addPartner = function(data) {
    $http.post(addPartner, data)
    .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $timeout($scope.loadPartnersData(), 5000)
    });        
    };

    $scope.removePartner = function(id) {
    var data = {"id": id}
    $http.post(removePartner, data)
    .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    });
    $scope.loadPartnersData();
    };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $scope.addPartner = function(data) {
    $http.post(addPartner, data)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.loadPartnersData();
        });
};
```

You were calling loadPartnersData() outside the http post promise, that caused it to run right away, probably before the add actually processed in the backend.

Will want to fix the remove, it has the same issue.

Comment: Well it doesn't work. After this i have to refresh by pressing CTRL+R

Comment: This still sounds like just an issue of your load being called too early (i.e. before the add is finished). How about this to figure out if its related: add a $timeout of 5 seconds and then call load. For instance: $timeout($scope.loadPartnersData(), 5000) //might want to double check the syntax for $timeout but I think its okay. Also, a console log for when the load function completes (i.e. $scope.partnerList is updated) and display whats coming back from the service after those 5 seconds.

Comment: @DiPix, I would think this should work. Are you getting an error either in the response or in JavaScript?

Comment: @DiPix, could you update your question to append what your current code looks like?

Comment: @DiPix what are you getting in the console? Nothing? Is the load function being called at all after the save is done? Add breakpoints or console.logs and help us understand whats "not working" :D

Comment: @DiPix, it's still outside the "then" function. Add it directly beneath your `console.log` statement.

Comment: @DiPix, what is `console.log` logging?

Comment: @adam0101, Nothing. Ouh so it looks like that promise never execute?`.then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $timeout($scope.loadPartnersData(), 5000)
        });` But why?

Comment: @DiPix, you'll have to check the response from the server using the developer tools or stepping through your server-side code, but wdanda's code is correct for the client-side. (You can remove that $timeout now too)

Comment: @adam0101, ok i found problem. In backend this is how response should looks like `res.json(response);` instead of this `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });` Thank you guys for help!